# syntax error on DELETE FROM LEFT INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im getting the following Error on my query:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "p"
```

This is my query:

```
  DELETE p FROM property_import_image_results p
  LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT q.created_at FROM property_import_image_results q
  WHERE q.external_url=p.external_url AND (q.listing_image_id = p.listing_image_id OR q.listing_image_id IS NULL)
  ORDER BY q.created_at DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 1) as qf ON p.created_at = qf.created_at
  WHERE qf.created_at is NULL;
```

Any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: postgres. I'll fix the question now.

Comment: DELETE FROM property_import_image_results p

Comment: You can't use `left join` like that in a DELETE statement: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-delete.html

Answer (score 2):

You cannot phrase your query this way.  Perhaps this is what you want:

```
DELETE FROM property_import_image_results p
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM property_import_image_results q
                      WHERE q.external_url = p.external_url AND
                            q.created_at > p.created_at AND 
                            (q.listing_image_id = p.listing_image_id OR  q.listing_image_id IS NULL)
                     ) ;
```

Comment: thanks @Gordon Linoff but I need the ORDER BY in order to get the last created result (im basically trying to get avary result, group by external_url, except the most recent one)

Comment: @ntonnelier . . . I see.  I changed the `=` to a `>`, which should get the most recent version for updating.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of p between DELETE and FROM clause : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp. So try to delete it.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource - probably professional rivalry, but just sayin'

Comment: Not the case when you intend to delete from JOIN. This was my first attempt actually..

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for the reference, I will use this reference to w3schools more carefully in the future.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not familiar with postgresql's specifics, aren't you essentially saying "delete mytable from mytable" in the beginning of your delete statement? Shouldn't that be "delete from property_import_image_results p ...etc. etc."?

Comment: Your answers will generally be better received if they are not phrased as questions.